# Cannot run tests against neo4j database in GitLab CI docker-in-docker

Tags: docker, neo4j, docker-compose, gitlab, ongdb

### The problem

I am trying to run my unit tests in GitLab CI. For my test setup, I am using docker-compose to start a database cluster of three neo4j instances, then I am running the tests on the docker host via localhost.

On my machine this works very well, so I tried to do the same on GitLab CI. I initially had some problems getting docker-compose to run inside the CI container, but I managed to get that working with the following .gitlab-ci.yaml:

```
image: "tiangolo/docker-with-compose:latest"

before_script:
    - apk add --update nodejs npm
    - npm install npm@latest -g
    - npm install

services:
  - docker:dind

run-test:
    script:
        - docker-compose up -d --build
        - npm test
```

The dependencies get installed, docker-compose starts the database successfully and `npm test` runs my unit tests. So far, so good. **But all tests that are using a database connection in some form fail, because they are not able to reach it on localhost:7687**. I get the following error message

```
Neo4jError: Could not perform discovery. No routing servers available. Known routing table: RoutingTable[database=default database, expirationTime=0, currentTime=1588275075260, routers=[], readers=[], writers=[]]
```

Keep in mind, I am using the same docker-compose.yaml on my local machine and everything works, so it shouldn't be a problem with the database configuration.

### What I tried already

I figured that my tests are running before the database is fully started, so I added a `sleep 120` like so

```
run-test:
    script:
        - docker-compose up -d --build
        - sleep 120
        - npm test
```

I even measured how long it takes for the cluster to start inside the CI container and chose the timeout appropriately, but no luck, the tests still fail.

Then I had a look at the docker networks, to see if something went wrong there

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.2  docker 3590cde9c5df runner-k3xtxnwc-project-17881831-concurrent-0-6d9d78b64ad6df95-docker-0
172.17.0.3  runner-k3xtxnwc-project-17881831-concurrent-0

$ docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' core1
172.19.0.2

$ docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' core2
172.19.0.4
```

But that looks good to me. I then tried to replace `localhost:7678` with `docker:7678`, `172.0.0.1` and even `$(docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' core1):7678`. But none of them work.

Trying to `curl localhost:7474` (the neo4j http console) returns `Failed to connect to localhost port 7474: Connection refused`

EDIT:

My docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'
services:
        dbc1:
                build: ./database
                container_name: core1
                hostname: core1
                ports:
                        - 7474:7474
                        - 7687:7687
                environment: 
                        - NEO4J_dbms_mode=CORE
                        - NEO4J_causal__clustering_minimum__core__cluster__size__at__formation=3
                        - NEO4J_causal__clustering_minimum__core__cluster__size__at__runtime=3
                        - NEO4J_causal__clustering_initial__discovery__members=core1:5000,core2:5000,core3:5000
                        - NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT=yes
                        - NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_advertised__address=localhost:7687
                        - NEO4J_dbms_connector_http_advertised__address=localhost:7474
                volumes:
                        - dbdata1:/data
                ulimits:
                        nofile:
                                soft: 40000
                                hard: 40000
        dbc2:
                build: ./database
                container_name: core2
                hostname: core2
                ports:
                        - 8474:7474
                        - 8687:7687
                environment: 
                        - NEO4J_dbms_mode=CORE
                        - NEO4J_causal__clustering_minimum__core__cluster__size__at__formation=3
                        - NEO4J_causal__clustering_minimum__core__cluster__size__at__runtime=3
                        - NEO4J_causal__clustering_initial__discovery__members=core1:5000,core2:5000,core3:5000
                        - NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT=yes
                        - NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_advertised__address=localhost:8687
                        - NEO4J_dbms_connector_http_advertised__address=localhost:8474
                volumes:
                        - dbdata2:/data
                ulimits:
                        nofile:
                                soft: 40000
                                hard: 40000
        dbc3:
                build: ./database
                container_name: core3
                hostname: core3
                ports:
                        - 9474:7474
                        - 9687:7687
                environment: 
                        - NEO4J_dbms_mode=CORE
                        - NEO4J_causal__clustering_minimum__core__cluster__size__at__formation=3
                        - NEO4J_causal__clustering_minimum__core__cluster__size__at__runtime=3
                        - NEO4J_causal__clustering_initial__discovery__members=core1:5000,core2:5000,core3:5000
                        - NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT=yes
                        - NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_advertised__address=localhost:9687
                        - NEO4J_dbms_connector_http_advertised__address=localhost:9474
                volumes:
                        - dbdata3:/data
                ulimits:
                        nofile:
                                soft: 40000
                                hard: 40000
volumes:
        dbdata1:
                driver: local
        dbdata2:
                driver: local
        dbdata3:
                driver: local
```

My database Dockerfile (located in ./database):

```
FROM graphfoundation/ongdb:3.6

RUN echo "* soft nofile 40000" >> /etc/security/limits.conf
RUN echo "* hard nofile 40000" >> /etc/security/limits.conf

## inject password change into startup script
# create alternative startup script
RUN echo "#!/bin/bash -eu" >> /docker-entrypoint-modified.sh 

# add command to change password
RUN echo "bin/neo4j-admin set-initial-password testpassword" >> /docker-entrypoint-modified.sh

# copy the contents of docker-entrypoint.sh, but skip the first line
RUN tail -n +2 /docker-entrypoint.sh >> /docker-entrypoint-modified.sh

# replace docker-entrypoint.sh with docker-entrypoint-modify
RUN cat /docker-entrypoint-modified.sh > /docker-entrypoint.sh


EXPOSE 7474 7473 7687
```

Comment: Can you share your `Dockerfile` to allow us to replicate your setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I had some misconceptions about docker-in-docker, I solved the problem by "rerouting" localhost to the docker-in-docker service by changing the following lines in my `.gitlab-ci.yaml`:

```
services:
  - docker:dind
```

to

```
services:
  - name: docker:dind
    alias: localhost
```